# Laravel/Eloquent: Constrain nested eager load so as not to include empty parents

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a relatively simple DB structure including countries, regions and depots. Each depot is assigned to an operator and a region:

---

operators

```
+----+------------+
| ID |    name    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Operator 1 |
|  2 | Operator 2 |
+----+------------+
```

---

countries

```
+----+----------------+------+
| ID |   country_id   | code |
+----+----------------+------+
|  1 | United Kingdom | gb   |
|  2 | France         | fr   |
+----+----------------+------+
```

---

regions

```
+----+-----------------+-------+
| ID | country_id (FK) | name  |
+----+-----------------+-------+
|  1 |               1 | North |
|  2 |               1 | South |
|  3 |               1 | East  |
|  4 |               1 | West  |
|  5 |               2 | North |
|  6 |               2 | South |
|  7 |               2 | East  |
|  8 |               2 | West  |
+----+-----------------+-------+
```

---

depots

```
+----+----------------+------------------+-----------+
| ID | region_id (FK) | operator_id (FK) |   name    |
+----+----------------+------------------+-----------+
|  1 |              1 |                1 | Newcastle |
|  2 |              8 |                2 | Nantes    |
+----+----------------+------------------+-----------+
```

---

I have set up their eloquent relationships successfully in the respective models.

I want to load each depot grouped into their respective regions and countries, and filtered by a specific operator.

```
$depots = Country::with('regions.depots')->whereHas('regions.depots', function($query) use ($opID) {
    $query->where('operator_id',$opID);
})->get();
```

This does the trick, however as well as eager loading the depots, it's also eager loading all regions, including those without depots assigned to them. E.G. when the above is performed when `$opID = 1`, you get this result:

```
name: United Kingdom,
regions: [
    {
        name: North,
        depots: [{
            name: Newcastle
        }]
    }, {
        name: South,
        depots: []
    }, {
        name: East,
        depots: []
    }, {
        name: West,
        depots: []
    }
]
```

**What I would like is the above returned, but without the regions where there are no depots.**

I have played around a lot with the constraints of both `with` and `whereHas` but cannot get the desired data structure. Why doesn't the below code have the desired effect?

```
$depots = Country::with(['regions.depots' => function($query) use ($opID) {
    $query->where('depots.operator_id',$opID);
}])->get();
```

Is there any way at all of not eagerly loading the parent if the child doesn't exist? Or is it a case of performing the above query as I have it and then looping through the result manually?

---

**EDIT**

So after a few more hours I finally found a way to get my desired outcome. But it seems really dirty. Is this really the best way?

```
$depots = Country::whereHas('regions.depots', function($q) use ($opID) {
    $q->where('operator_id',$opID);
})->with(['regions' => function($q) use ($opID) {
    $q->with('depots')->whereHas('depots', function($q2) use ($opID) {
        $q2->where('operator_id',$opID);
    });
}])->get();
```

---

**EDIT 2**

So it turns out the first edit was actually querying the `operator_id` on everything but the `depots` table, which meant as soon as I added another depot owned by another operator in the same region, that showed up when I didn't want it to. The below seems even messier but does work. It's fun having conversations with myself ;) Hopefully it helps someone one day...

```
$depots = Country::has('regions.depots')
          ->with(['regions' => function($q) use ($opID) {
              $q->with(['depots' => function($q2) use ($opID) {
                  $q2->where('operator_id',$opID);
              }])->has('depots');
          }])->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use lazy loading:

```
$depots = Country::whereHas('regions.depots', function($q) use ($opID) {
    $q->where('operator_id',$opID);
})->get()->load('regions.depots');
```

Comment: Thanks but this appears to have the same results as in my initial code block